# Linq replace blank with string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, collections

I have a linq statement here, I get "null" in the "surname" (u.Surname) field. I want to replace this with "blank" keyword, before hitting the return statement.else return will not return rows with blank.

```
 var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.Where(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Surname) && ( u.Surname.ToLower().StartsWith(textValue) || u.Surname.ToUpper().StartsWith(textValue.ToUpper()))), Formatting.Indented);
```

Present

```
Lastname FirstName email 
          ABC       abc@email.com
Something DEF       def@email.com
          ghg       ghg@email.com
```

Expected

```
Lastname FirstName email 
blank     ABC       abc@email.com
Something DEF       def@email.com
blank     ghg       ghg@email.com
```

Could you please let me know how to do this?

[image: Error in the following line]

```
var users = user.Select(u => { u.Surname = u.Surname ?? "blank"; return u; });
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: Im surprised you get surnames that are blank given the first criteria is !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Surname)..

Comment: if i remove , code will break, because of u.null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have this `textValue` constraint, it would be much better to move this to the Graph query. That would solve the null problem at the source.

You can fold your 3 (!) tests into one, when `u.surname.ToUpper() .StartsWith(textValue.ToUpper())` you don't have to check the other ToLower() and neutral versions.

But I'm not sure how to do that in MS Graph.

If you still do want to filter after the query:

```
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

var user2 = user
   .Select(u => { u.Surname = u.Surname ?? "blank"; return u; })
   .Where(u => u.surname.ToUpper().StartsWith(textValue.ToUpper())
   ;

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user2, Formatting.Indented ));
```

Comment: type caste issue

Comment: see the image in your answer

Comment: @SmartestVEGA don't edit answers to include errors you get when implementing them.

Comment: check now Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Graph.User>' to 'Microsoft.Graph.IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)